# Replace 'right' with 'left' and 'left' with 'right' in a .css file in case arabic

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I have a file called bootstrap.css.scss. I want to add Right to Left support for it. In order to do so I need to replace all the occurrences of the string 'right' with 'left' and all the occurrences of the string 'left' with 'right' in that file. How can I do that in purchaded theme

Comment: "Register-transfer-level"? Please check your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to change CSS at all, that’s inefficient and prone to error, especially if you’re trying to change third-party code.

You can use the `dir` attribute set to `“rtl”` on `<html>`and it will change the directionality of content which includes swapping the behavior of the CSS properties `left` and `right` to their opposite. It does what you want by changing a single element, the `html` or root element.

That would be

```
<html dir=“rtl”>
```

More here: [dir global attribute in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir)

If you’re totally set on manually changing all the CSS, I advise against it, because doing so with this attribute is best practice and compatible with more browsers and implementations. But if that doesn’t matter to you, find the docs for your theme provider or contact them to see how you can edit the CSS.

Otherwise, remember CSS is Cascading, which means if you load a CSS file after your theme’s CSS that targets the same [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and merely changes the values of `right` and `left` then it will override the values in your theme.